# Как из двух чисел составить одно? Конкатенация чисел как массива бит

Tags: c++

Нужно у двух чисел равной длины (в битах) поменять местами хвост и голову. Например `42 = 101010`, `36 = 100100`, после должно получится `010100` и `100101`.
Как это реализовать в C++?

Comment: В массив, а потом задом на перед массив читаешь куда надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предположении, что битовая длина известна, и суммарная длина меньше 32, можно выполнить операции, собрав оба числа в одном двойном слове:

```
int a = 42;                                          // b101010
int b = 36;                                          // b100100

int len = 6;                                         // bit length
int halflen = len / 2;

int mask = (1 << len) - 1;                           // b111111
int halfmask = (1 << halflen) - 1;                   // b111
int single = (a << len) | (b << 0);                  // a0 a1 b0 b1
int c = (single >> halflen) & mask;                  // a1 b0
int d = (((single >> 0) & halfmask) << halflen)
      | (((single >> halflen * 3) & halfmask) << 0); // b1 a0

cout << bitset<6>(a) << " " << bitset<6>(b) << endl;
cout << bitset<32>(mask) << " " << bitset<32>(halfmask) << endl;
cout << bitset<32>(single) << endl;
cout << bitset<6>(c) << " " << bitset<6>(d) << endl;
```

Общая идея при извлечении битов такая: сдвинуть вправо, чтобы нужные биты оказались младшими; урезать маской нужные биты; сдвинуть влево на нужное место. Как вариант, можно двигать маску (наверное, так даже проще будет...).

Вывод:

```
101010 100100
00000000000000000000000000111111 00000000000000000000000000000111
00000000000000000000101010100100
010100 100101
```

Вычисление битовой длины оставляю как домашнее задание.

Answer (score 3):

1. Сначала стоит определить длину: нужно целочисленно делить число на 2 `a/2` до тех пор пока оно не обратится в 0. Например:`5/2 = 2; 2/2 = 1; 1/2 = 0;` - произвели 3 деления, значит в число состоит из 3 бит.
2. Теперь можно перевести число в двоичную систему: `5%2 = 1; 2%2 = 0; 1%2 = 1;`
   Получили число 101 (читать остатки надо в обратном порядке). Это число можно сохранить в массив.
3. Сделав аналогично с другим числом те же действия, надо просто соорудить новые массивы, где хвост и голова от разных чисел.
4. Перевести в десятичную систему можно так: `m[0]*(2^(n-1)) + m[1]*(2^(n-2)) + ... + m[n-1]*2(n-n)`, где m - массив битов (а точнее 0 и 1), n - длина числа.

Первый пункт можно объединить со вторым, если использовать вместо массива vector или список.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю найденное мной решение. Хотя оно меняет только хвосты (оказалось, что и этот вариант подойдет), его легко подправить на случай, если нужно поменять хвост и голову:

```
void coop(int &x, int &y, int n)
{
    long long buf=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
    buf+=x%2;
    cout << buf << endl;
    buf<<=1;
    cout << buf << endl;
    x>>=1;
}
for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    buf+=y%2;
    cout << buf << endl;
    buf<<=1;
    cout << buf << endl;
    y>>=1;
}
buf>>=1;
cout << buf << endl;
for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    x<<=1;
    x+=buf%2;
    buf>>=1;
}
for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    y<<=1;
    y+=buf%2;
    buf>>=1;
}


}
```

Функция меняет местами хвосты размером 'n' у чисел 'y' и 'x', длиной больше 'n'